# Django Project is not hosting in Cpanel

Tags: django, cpanel, host

[Problem occuring](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DUAcV.png)

My Django project is not hosting on cpanel. I have created 2 app in my django project(Affiliate, members). [app and project file](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cg0BY.png)

This message is showing in my domain when I hosted :
We're sorry, but something went wrong.
The issue has been logged for investigation. Please try again later.

Technical details for the administrator of this website:
Error ID:
9d01091b
Details:
Web application could not be started by the Phusion Passenger application server.

Please read the Passenger log file (search for the Error ID) to find the details of the error.

You can also get a detailed report to appear directly on this page, but for security reasons it is only provided if Phusion Passenger is run with environment set to development and/or with the friendly error pages option set to on.

For more information about configuring environment and friendly error pages, see:

Nginx integration mode
Apache integration mode
Standalone mode

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Standart hosting providers doesn't support python or django. You should use ssh and manual installation.

Comment: Sir is there any documentation or any video can you provide me, please?

Comment: There is different scenarios based on your server's operating system and configration. You can get an idea from here: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.1/howto/deployment/